# Synonymize [ble] and [bluetooth-lowenergy]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, synonym-request

I'm an iOS developer who in the past has worked with connected object, and Bluetooth Low-Energy (which is often abbreviated as BLE). I got some points related to [core-bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-bluetooth) *(CoreBluetooth.framework is the iOS framework for BLE stuff)*, and [bluetooth-lowenergy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-lowenergy), it's not to brag (clearly no points in that), but more to say that I'm not totally a newbie in that domain and that my proposal seems legit.

I'm watching *Bluetooth Low-Energy* related tags in order to help if possible, and I stumbled into a possible duplicate case for tags: [ble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ble) & [bluetooth-lowenergy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-lowenergy).

They clearly designate the same thing, [ble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ble) being less popular and less informed (in a Wiki meaning).

I [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) to put them as synonyms, but it seems that it may be faster with the Meta Stack Overflow community.